# Deriving day level forecasts from week level forecasts?

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I already have week level forecasts for multiple SKUs. I want to get day level forecasts. Is there a way to derive the day level forecasts from the week level forecasts?
I could potentially create a separate model for day level forecasts. But I want to know if there is some way I could use the existing model.
If there are literature on similar methods, kindly point me towards it.

Answer (score 0):

The existing weekly forecast can be broken down to days by computing the average % of the weekly sales for each weekday. A more detailed explanation: https://otexts.com/fpp2/top-down.html

Comment: Since daily data (and weekly sums) can be influenced by holidays and other anthropogenic factors and of course autocorrelation effects .. it might be prudent to consider a daily model.

Comment: Yes indeed, if that is an option, I agree.